# Number of rows for the subset of the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe `A_df` loads the dataset that contains information on a number of categories regarding traffic (`cnt`). I must print the number of rows for the subset of the dataframe for which traffic values are higher than 10,000 (ideally, you should format the print to put the thousands comma separator--as in 23,400 instead of 23400).

My code below is not showing me the correct output.

```
rate = a_df.loc[a_df['cnt'] > 10000]
print(rate)
```

Comment: so what is the problem ? wrong rows number or wrong formatted output ?

Comment: @MehrdadKhojastefar I need to the print number of rows for the subset of the dataframe for which traffic values are higher than 10,000

Comment: so you just want your code to print 10,000 instead of 10000 ?

Comment: @MehrdadKhojastefar that is part of it. I also need to print "number of rows for the subset of the dataframe for which traffic values are higher than 10,000"

Comment: Could you give an example of the output in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for separating the digits:

```
print(f"{rate:,}") # python ≥ 3.6
'{:,}'.format(rate) # python ≥ 2.7
```

for printing the length of your array :

```
print(len(rate))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of entries in your dataframe subset, just use:

```
n_entries = len(rate.index())
print(n_entries)
```

Regarding printing with the comma separator: it's just a matter of formatting. You could use something like:

```
print(f'{n_entries//1000},{n_entries-n_entries//1000*1000}' )
```